# How to Limit Connections for user

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am making a download script which will be used to download files from some sites they don't have access to. I also have to provide resume support but as IDM and many new download managers use 8-16 connection or even more. I found most of the users are using 20-25 conections for each file. I have to provide unlimited file downloads and speed also but limit connections for every file. I can slow down the load and the users don't have a problem with that.

I am confused how to do it. Can it done using htaceess? Also I thought I could do it by making some continuous log but I am still confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly recommend `limitipconn.c` on an Apache server.

```
http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn.html
```

An example of usage would be

```
<IfModule mod_limitipconn.c>
     <Location /your-download-directory>
          MaxConnPerIP 3
     </Location>
</IfModule>
```

---

If you prefer solving this problem with PHP and a database (such as MySQL used in this example)

```
<?php
// Allow this amount of concurrent connections
$max_connections = 100;

// User's IP
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Sanitized file name
$current_download = mysql_real_escape_string( 'download-file.zip' );

$query_count = mysql_query( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM connections WHERE user_ip = '{$user_ip}'" );

// Amount of concurrent connections this user has running
list( $current_connections ) = mysql_fetch_array( $current_connections_query );

if( $current_connections < $max_downloads ) {
     // Insert this connection to database
     mysql_query( "INSERT INTO connections (user_ip, current_download) VALUES('{$user_ip}','{$current_download}')" );

     // This will remove this connection from the database when script finished
     register_shutdown_function('download_ended');

     // your code to download file goes here ...
}

else {
     // your code to run when user has maximum concurrent connections
     exit;
}

// Removes download session from database
function download_ended() {
     global $current_download, $user_ip;

     // Session complete, subtract one
     mysql_query( "DELETE FROM connections WHERE current_download = '{$current_download}' AND user_ip = '{$user_ip}' LIMIT 1" );
}
?>
```

Comment: well i have to limit connection per file not per ip anyways your point is good any make it with that but what if user pause the download will download_ended function will call that time too or online after finishing any response ? i understand ur concept and it is good but have still some cunfusion

Comment: @ash – When you pause a download, it aborts connection and saves the data it has already received. This would invoke the download_ended function. To have the ability to resume a download will require some extra code within PHP if you are implicitly including the file. When the download is resumed, it checks how many bytes it has and sends a "Range" header in the request to tell your server what byte range to start at, so it continues to get data after the data you've already received. Hope this makes sense

Comment: you were right actually the require file is not a file it is a remote file and i should not use db i am using md5(fileid.ip) as an download it and make a temporary file for logs . but how will i know that the user have downloaded 100% so i can deleet the log and delete the remote file .

Comment: Create a function that '[unlink](http://php.net/unlink)' (deletes) the file, and call register_shutdown_function with the function's name. This will delete that file when the download is paused/stopped/completed, and the file should be created whenever the file is started/resumed.

Comment: wow ur idea is great . thanks . but i have to send a request to remote server to delete that file as the file was streaming from a remote location . when user completes the download i should send them some req but not when the resume/pause the download . how abt it this s very important to me plz help . thanks

Answer (score 1):

Limit the number of simultaneous downloads:

```
http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn.html
http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn2.html
```

BTW: This has nothing to do with mod-rewrite

Comment: well actually the main page is download.php?fileid= but i made it files/fileid/filename to look better that requires mod-rewrite . anyways will this limitpconn will limit globalconnection from that ip or coonection from each file ?

Answer (score 0):

> > http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn2.html
> >
> > By default, all clients behind a proxy are treated as coming from the
> >        proxy server's IP address. If you wish to alter this behavior,
> >        use the mod_remoteip module included in Apache 2.4.

I am facing almost exactly the same issue here, because if user adds a file in IDM, every connection consumes ~ 15MB of RAM and it slows down the site. I have limited the MaXClients but still if you find any good solution then please do share.